# Struts2 Interceptors and Spring Integration

Tags: spring, struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

My question is a bit basic since I'm still learning up on Struts2 and Spring, and their integration. When we define an interceptor in the struts.xml e.g.

```xml
<interceptors>
  <interceptor name="validation" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor"/> 

  <interceptor-stack name="simpleStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
      <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,execute</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
  </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<default-interceptor-ref name="simpleStack"/>
```

And if in the applicationContext.xml I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
          "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
 <bean id="user" class="struts.model.User"/>
     <bean id="registerUserAction" class="struts.actions.UserInformationAction">
         <property name="userBean" ref="user"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="chooseUsernamePasswordAction" class="struts.actions.ChooseUsernameAction">
        <property name="userBean" ref="user"/>
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

Without the interceptor defined the user bean is persistent across both actions (registerUserAction -> JSP -> chooseUsernamePasswordAction) and i can access the properties. Once the interceptor is introduced it looks like the values are nulled out.

1. First from what i read it looks like i might be doing this all wrong. i.e. with Spring integrated all these items are in singleton default mode which might not be right since multiple users will be registering and so each would have to have their own Action/User beans.
2. What is happening or needs to be done to pass information across and have the interceptors working right.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you are explicitly defining your actions in the Spring config they must be defined as `scope="prototype"`. It's relatively unusual you'd need to define them manually, unless you specifically want to use XML configuration for everything, like service injection and so on.

It's not entirely clear to me what your intent is with the user bean. You *may* use a Spring session-scoped bean, available with the Spring web contexts. I'm not sure how necessary that is; I've usually done it manually and retrieved the bean from the session when I actually need it. Likely doesn't matter.

Note also that your stack eliminates essentially *all* Struts 2 functionality, like the conversion of form parameters to action properties. This *may* be what you intend, but it's unlikely.

Comment: Defining actions in the application context is OK in my opinion, but as Dave said, you probably want to scope them as __prototype__, and you probably want to sope your user bean as __session__. Also as Dave said, before you set your interceptor stack in place, the user's properties are injected as you expect. But with your stack, because you removed parameters injection, user's properties are left unchanged

Comment: Thanks folks. To clarify my intention, think of the userbean as the bean that would contain all user related information i.e. name, address, username. These get populated as the flow of registration proceeds, i.e. first enter basic information do some validation stuff and in another page choose username and stuff etc. So I'm essentially populating the bean as i go along - thus session. Can you guys elaborate on what you mean when you say my stack eliminates all struts2 functionality and about parameters injection.What if I had multiple interceptors e.g CreateSession, custom interceptors

Comment: @user1111871 There's nothing to elaborate on; the `"simpleStack"` you create and use as the default stack contains only a single interceptor. Most S2 functionality beyond request mapping comes from interceptors you don't have in your stack.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [struts-default.xml](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/struts-defaultxml.html). Now check out the interceptor stack named *defaultStack*. At the end of the document, this stack is set as the default interceptor stack. As Dave Newton explained, all the magic of struts 2 comes from its interceptors.

Basically, when you set your stack as default stack, you replace a stack that contains 17 interceptors by one that contains only 1. By doing so you gave up many struts 2 functionalities like parameter injection for example, provided by the interceptor *param*.

Also, note that the validation interceptor is included in *defaultStack*, but with different parameter *excludeMethods*.

Answer (score 0):

We also using same project structure

Struts2+Spring+Hibernate

Before using the Struts interceptor, we can able to pass the parameter

But after using the interceptor, we are not able to send the parameters (values are null)

To avoid that, use `params` interceptor, then you can pass the parameters

e.g.:

```
<action name="doUpload_valid1" method="importExcel" class="validationAction">
  <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>

  <result name="error">jsp/cmdbValidPage.jsp</result> 
  <result name="success">jsp/testJob.jsp</result> 
</action>
```